# How to Access Data of Models of OneToOneFiled Django ORM

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am using User in-built model. Now i am query in UserListView to exclude all users who is Super Admin where Role is stored in `Roles Model`. I dont know how to query `queryset = User.objects.exclude(user_user_role_id=1)` This is problem please help me to Query

```
class UserListView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'users/users.html'
    context_object_name = 'users'
    queryset = User.objects.exclude(user_user_role_id=1)


UserProfile Model
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_role = models.ForeignKey(Roles, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Roles(models.Model):
    role_title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    role_description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes i Found it. Just have to use double underscores

```
queryset = User.objects.exclude(userprofile__user_role_id=1)
```

OR

```
queryset = User.objects.exclude(userprofile__user_role__role_title='Super Admin')
```